# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 in example from Java In A Nutshell

Tags: java, cryptography, indexoutofboundsexception

I wanted to try out the code from Java In A Nutshell book (3rd edition), but when I'm trying to run it, I'm getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` error. I found that info:

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

but unfortunately I am still not able to find and fix it

```
package tripledes;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TripleDES {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Installing SunJCE provicer");
            Provider sunjce = new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE();
            Security.addProvider(sunjce);
        }

        File keyfile = new File(args[1]);

        if (args[0].equals("-g")) {
            System.out.println("Generating key. This may take some time...");
            System.out.flush();
            SecretKey key = generateKey();
            writeKey(key, keyfile);
            System.out.println("Done");
            System.out.println("Secret key written to " + args[1] + ". Protect that file!");
        } else if (args[0].equals("-e")) {
            SecretKey key = readKey(keyfile);
            encrypt(key, System.in, System.out);
        } else if (args[0].equals("-d")) {
            SecretKey key = readKey(keyfile);
            decrypt(key, System.in, System.out);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        System.err.println("Usage: java " + TripleDES.class.getName() + "-d|-e|-g <keyfile>");
    }

}

public static SecretKey generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
    return keygen.generateKey();
}

public static void writeKey(SecretKey key, File f) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
    DESedeKeySpec keyspec = (DESedeKeySpec) keyfactory.getKeySpec(key, DESedeKeySpec.class);
    byte[] rawkey = keyspec.getKey();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
    out.write(rawkey);
    out.close();
}

public static SecretKey readKey(File f) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    byte[] rawkey = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    in.readFully(rawkey);
    in.close();

    DESedeKeySpec keyspec = new DESedeKeySpec(rawkey);
    SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
    SecretKey key = keyfactory.generateSecret(keyspec);
    return key;
}

public static void encrypt(SecretKey key, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        cos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    cos.close();

    java.util.Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0);
}

public static void decrypt(SecretKey key, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        NoSuchPaddingException, BadPaddingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
    }
    out.write(cipher.doFinal());
    out.flush();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you tell on which line you are getting the exception

Comment: We don't know how you're running it, where the exception is, or what you've done to diagnose the problem yourself. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I didn't know which line the exception was, that was part of the problem. But nvm. thanks to J.Borgh's answer i figured out that I just forgot to set program arguments. Sorry for bothering with such stupid thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be when you access the args array. Such as:

```
 File keyfile = new File(args[1]);
```

If you have no arguments to your program then this would be an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Thanks to your answer i figured out that I just forgot to set program arguments. Sorry for bothering with such stupid thing and thanks for help